# Why can't 了 be used to complement 到?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, usage

I have been taught that the sentence 我刚到了 (wǒ gāng dào le) is not correct because 了 cannot be used as a complement of 到. Is this right? If so, why?

Comment: Hello ncasas, I removed the "strong" tags because characters this way are thinner and therefore, ironically, more visible. :)

Comment: Can you provide some context, e.g., the conversation setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

我刚到了 is perfectly understandable in oral communication. Your teacher probably thinks this is verbose because:

刚 = just

了 = already

我刚到了 = I just arrived already

Answer (score 1):

Before you provide more context, I would say this could be perfectly understood by people except that it might not sound that natural.

Depending on the context, you would prefer to say:

> 我刚到

or

> 我到了

Comment: How about sentences like 他到了没有？， 你看到了没有,？他什么时候到了? etc. These all sound natural to me? Is it only in the context of "刚到" that using 了 sounds unnatural? If so why?

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 I guess it has to do with 刚，which in this case means just (arrived). On the other hand, 了 indicates have arrived (complete tense). So I believe you are right, 刚 makes it unnatural. By the way, 他什么时候到了? sounds unnatural to my ears.

Comment: For 他什么时候到了 how about if an old friend has been in the country for a couple of months and you only just heard about it and you want to ask when they arrived? I thought it should be 他什么时候到悉尼？ _When will she be arriving in Sydney_ and 他什么时候到悉尼了？ _When did she arrive in Sydney?_ Can this second sentence be shortened to 他什么时候到了? when used in context? Or can you suggest a better alternative I should use? Thanks!

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 You should say 他什么时候到的悉尼 instead. In other words, replace 了 with 的.

Comment: Dunno. My southwestern friends put "ne" after just about every present-tense sentence, and "le" after ever past-tense sentence. One calls it a "go" word (as in: every sentence needs a word at the end to "go" ). Sure it's redundant, but bejeezus, just about all modern written Chinese has redundancy, given that one character words would often suffice where dual-character words are used today.